# Angular2 access @Input from class inside constructor that calls a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular2 and Typescript. I am trying to gain access to a @Input from the constructor in my class. A service is called from inside the constructor and I need to pass it an argument.

```
@Component({
    selector:'side-menu',
    templateUrl:'menu.html',
    providers:    [MenuService]
 })

export class SideMenuComponent {
    @Input() blockType;

    menuItems

    constructor(menuService:MenuService){
        this.menuItems = menuService.getMenuItems(this.blockType); // Sends Undefined
        this.menuItems = menuService.getMenuItems('HardCodedString'); //This works
    }


}
```

and this is my Service

```
    @Injectable()

export class MenuService {
    getMenuItems(type) {
        console.log(type)

        switch(type){
            case 'Thing':

                return [];
                break;
            case 'Otherthing':
                return [];
                break;
            default:
                return [];


        }

    }
}
```

How can I ensure the @Input gets sent to the service?

Comment: Which version are you using of Angular2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs are not yet set when the constructor is called. Move the constructor code to `ngOnInit()` instead.

```
@Component({
    selector:'side-menu',
    templateUrl:'menu.html',
    providers:    [MenuService]
 })

export class SideMenuComponent {
    @Input() blockType;

    menuItems

    constructor(private menuService:MenuService){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menuItems = this.menuService.getMenuItems(this.blockType); // Sends Undefined
        this.menuItems = this.menuService.getMenuItems('HardCodedString'); //This works
    }
}
```

Every time `@Input()`s are updated `ngOnChanges()` is called.
`ngOnInit()` is called after `ngOnChanges()` was called the first time.

Comment: Tried this and get : core.umd.js:3464 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: menuService is not defined

Comment: Sounds like you are missing an import for `MenuService` (like `import {MenuService} from './menu.service'`)

Comment: @yurzui edited my answer and fixed some other issues I copied from your question - thanks!

Comment: Works! Thank you!